# Prove that the range of $f$ is not closed.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, functions

I am having trouble computing the range of a function  $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$. My thinking would be that you just find the range of $\frac{2x}{x^2 +1}$ and the range of $\frac{x^2 -1}{x^2 +1}$ and take the intersection of the two, which would end up being $(-1, 1)$ but I'm just taking a wild guess. Here is the full question. Any help on a solutuin would be great.

Define $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ by

$f(x) = (\frac{2x}{x^2 +1} , \frac{x^2 - 1}{x^2 +1})$

Prove that the range of $f$ is not closed.

Comment: Note that $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)=(0,1).$ Show that it is an accumulation point of the graph that doesn't belong to the graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The range is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$, so intersecting two subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ is clearly not a viable way to go about this. Rather, the range is whatever curve $f$ follows in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and, since the function is continuous, there are only two places where the range might not contain its boundary and thus not be closed - that is, at the start and end of the curve. In particular, notice that
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}f(x)=(0,1)$$
meaning that the point $(0,1)$ is on the boundary of the range of $f$. However, $f$ never obtains that value, meaning it is outside the range of $f$. Since the range of $f$ does not contain all of its boundary, it is not closed.

(Explicitly, you could prove that the range of $f$ is the unit circle, minus the point $(0,1)$, which is not closed)

Comment: why wouldn't (-1, 0) be apart of the range?